# UITabBarController in code Not showing navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

We have created a UITabBarController in Obj C code using storyboards.  It works fine, however the navigation bars do not show on any of the views.  Have tried creating the nav bars in the TabBarController and bunch of others things.  Most samples do not show nav bars...Any specific code examples would be appreciated, thanks!  Here is the VDL code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITabBarItem * startTab = [[UITabBarItem  alloc]initWithTitle:@"Home" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HomeTab.png"] tag:0]; 
     UITabBarItem * helpTab = [[UITabBarItem  alloc]initWithTitle:@"Help" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"InfoDarkTab.png"] tag:1]; 

     UIStoryboard * phone = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
     StartListTVC *startVC = [phone instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StartList"];
     HelpWebVC * helpVC  = [phone instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HelpWeb"];

     startVC.tabBarItem = startTab;
     helpVC.tabBarItem  = helpTab;

     NSArray *myViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
         startVC,
         helpVC, nil];

    [self setViewControllers:myViewControllers];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should embed your view controllers in UINavigationController, not UITabBarController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITabBarItem * startTab = [[UITabBarItem  alloc]initWithTitle:@"Home" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HomeTab.png"] tag:0]; 
     UITabBarItem * helpTab = [[UITabBarItem  alloc]initWithTitle:@"Help" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"InfoDarkTab.png"] tag:1]; 

     UIStoryboard * phone = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
     StartListTVC *startVC = [phone instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StartList"];
     HelpWebVC * helpVC  = [phone instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HelpWeb"];


     UINavigationController *startNavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: startVC];
UINavigationController *helpNavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: helpVC];
     startNavVC.tabBarItem = startTab;
     helpNavVC.tabBarItem  = helpTab;
     NSArray *myViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
         startNavVC,
         helpNavVC];

    [self setViewControllers:myViewControllers];
    }
```

Comment: Correct.  Quite impressive for a newbie.  Thanks!

Comment: One small issue.  The nav buttons appear high in the status bar on launch and then align properly..as the tabs are touched...Buttons are created in code.

Comment: Oh, you should give more details on it. Put it here, or, for best, create a new question. But I think it won't be hard to get it on yourself :)

Comment: Ok, Here is the question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58286874/uitabbarviewcontroller-navigation-item-in-displays-in-status-bar-area-on-launch